# JPA/Hibernate - How to cascade delete from an entity that has no reference to the one to cascade to?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I use JPA with Hibernate.

I have a User class and a Flag class :

```
class User
{
    // ...
}

class Flag
{
    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    private User user;

}
```

I dont want/need a reference to the Flag object in the User class (and that's the main point). But when I delete a User, *I'd like the associated Flag (if there's one) to be deleted too*, without any ***foreign key constraint fails*** exception!

I know I could add a reference to the Flag inside the User, like :

```
class User
{
    @OneToOne(optional=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Flag flag;
}
```

And then the Flag object would be deleted when I delete the user.

But is it possible to cascade delete the Flag *without* having a reference to it in the User?

If not, what if the correct way to delete such an object?

Comment: Do you have a separate user and flag table? How do they look like? You use the *@OneToOne* annotation in your last example, which indicates to me that every unique user can have a unique flag associated with it. It seems weird (if you do have separate tables, that is). Care to explain what are you trying to achieve with all this? It feels to me that you're making this hard for yourself. Anyway, without a reference, your best bet is using triggers or specifying *on {delete,update} cascade* at table level.

Comment: Róbert, thanks for helping. The Flag class is indeed just an example. An example closer to my real application would be a "ContactRequest" entity : A user can create one (and only one) ContactRequest. The ContactRequest instance will exist in the database until an admin contact the user. But if the user creates a ContactRequest and then deletes his account, I want everything associated with the user to be deleted too, without "foreign key constraint fails" exceptions. Also : when you say "I could use triggers at table level", you mean *in the database itself*, not in JPA, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cascade the delete automatically in this case, you'll need to implement your own delete.

When you delete a user, first run a query like:

```
delete from Flag F where F.userId = :userId
```

Comment: Thanks MattR. I'll mark this as the answer is no one suggests something else.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which database you're using, so I'll assume it to be MySQL.

These are our tables. Note the one-to-one mapping between a *user_id* and a *user_flag_id* and the *on delete cascade on update cascade* clause.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `user_flag` (
  `user_flag_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_flag_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_flag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_flag_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Given these, you can create mappings like the followings.

```
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(schema = "test", name = "user")
public final class User {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  public int id;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "user_name")
  public String name;
}

@Entity(name = "user_flag")
@Table(schema = "test", name = "user_flag")
public final class UserFlag {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "user_flag_id")
  public int id;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "user_flag_name")
  public String name;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_flag_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
  public User user;
}
```

Let's assume we have the following data.

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Joe       |
|       2 | Jane      |
|       3 | Jacob     |
+---------+-----------+

+--------------+----------------+
| user_flag_id | user_flag_name |
+--------------+----------------+
|            1 | Joe's flag     |
|            3 | Jacob's flag   |
+--------------+----------------+
```

The following code will demonstrate that without any hassle, if you delete a user its associated flag will be deleted (but not the other way around).

```
@Test
public void test() {
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

  // prints out our three users, Joe, Jane and Jacob
  for (User u : em.createQuery(String.format("select u from %s u", User.class.getName()), User.class)
      .getResultList())
    System.out.format("User{id=%s, name=%s}\n", u.id, u.name);

  // prints out Joe's and Jacob's flags
  for (UserFlag uf : em.createQuery(String.format("select uf from %s uf", UserFlag.class.getName()), UserFlag.class)
      .getResultList())
    System.out.format("UserFlag{id=%s, name=%s}\n", uf.id, uf.name);

  et.begin();
  User jacob = em.find(User.class, 3);
  em.remove(jacob);
  et.commit();

  // prints out our remaining users, Joe and Jane
  for (User u : em.createQuery(String.format("select u from %s u", User.class.getName()), User.class)
      .getResultList())
    System.out.format("User{id=%s, name=%s}\n", u.id, u.name);

  // prints out Joe's flag
  for (UserFlag uf : em.createQuery(String.format("select uf from %s uf", UserFlag.class.getName()), UserFlag.class)
      .getResultList())
    System.out.format("UserFlag{id=%s, name=%s}\n", uf.id, uf.name);

  em.close();
  emf.close();
}
```

This example assumes that your engine of choice is InnoDB. If however you've wanted to use MyISAM you can [simulate the *on update cascade on delete cascade* clause using triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Róbert, I understand you suggest managing the cascade process at the table level. But is that a good/standard practice, when dealing with a JPA application? Isn't it confusing to manage some of the cascades as annotations and some others in the database itself?

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this if you were using any kind of in-memory caching of hibernate entities/queries - Hibernate wouldn't know that the flag had been removed so it would still exist in the cache (at least until some timeout)

Comment: @electrotype Is it confusing? Yes, but you didn't ask whether what you're trying to do is confusing or not. I tried to imply in my first comment, that what you're about to do seems weird and as it turns out you can already see that. If you have other entities where you handle relationships in a JPA-fashion then I can't see why you want to hide this particular relationship. With my solution Hibernate's caching is only an issue if you have a horrible amount of users. Declare the relationship on both sides but restrict access on the user side.

Comment: *"Declare the relationship on both sides but restrict access on the user side."* : This is what I'll do actually. I think it is the cleanest way to manage the cascade. I simply won't add any getter/setter for it in the User class. But, the best answer to my original question is the one by MattR, in my opinion. I don't like the idea to manage the cascade both as annotations and at table level. Thanks for the help Róbert!